# What does "chow-wow" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across a new word while reading Newspaper - **chow-wow**.  This context is a Cooking Fiesta workshop happening in the city.

**Excerpt from the Newspaper:**

> . . . . . "Well, you'll just have to invite me
>   over for dinner so I can check if  you're as good as you claim to be!"
>   piped chef Nikhil in jest, much in keeping with the **chow-wow** of
>   the event.

What does **chow-wow** mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Chow-wow* is not a real English word, but it is a portmanteau based on the words *pow-wow* and *chow*. [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chow-wow) says *chow-wow* is:

> A meeting of the minds, business or casual, where food is served

A [*pow-wow*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pow-wow)  is a "meeting or conference", and *chow* is an informal word for "food". So a *chow-wow* is a meeting at which there is food. This makes sense in your context--the speaker is talking about being invited over to taste someone's food, so it is a literal meeting at which eating is a big part.

Comment: As additional note, _chow down_ is informally used to mean _eat_.